# Draytek, Vigor 2926, Open Ports, Lan 2-8

Tags: networking, router, vigor

I cannot open a port / port redirect to a computer on LAN2,3,4

Opening a port / port redirection works for LAN 1. (Tested with a webserver on port 80)

LAN#1 : 10.0.16.*
LAN#2 : 10.0.15.*

It doesn't matter if Lan 2 Network configuration is set "For NAT Usage" or "For Routing Usage", neither work.

Firewall>>Diagnose - says the packets are not handled by the firewall.

Ports are open on the computer on Lan#2 I want to direct the port traffic to. (Tested with a webserver from Lan#1)

Inter-LAN Routing works for LAN1 - LAN2 (Webserver on Lan#2 uses a database on Lan#1, Lan#1 uses a webserver on Lan#2)

The Draytek, Vigor2926 management port do not conflict with the ports I want to open.

Open Port setting:

```
WAN Interface: All
Source IP: Any
Private IP: 10.0.15.X
TCP/UDP : 80 - 80
```

On a previous Draytek router all of this worked. I have 4 LANs 3 with a service to port forward.

I will try updating the firmware at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Don't NAT. Don't redirect. Don't forward ports. Just route.

Make sure the router is set as default gateway on either side (or add static routes on all devices). Set up a firewall policy to allow routing in both directions. Go.